# Processing.py - Unknown Error on Class Definition

Tags: python, processing

I have no idea how to fix this error.

Maybe there's an open parenthesis or quotation mark somewhere before this line?

What is wrong with this code?

```
Class Ribbon: # I got an error on this line!
def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, m, g):
    self.x=xpos
    self.y=ypos
    self.mass=m
    self.gravity=g
    ..

def update(self, xpos, ypos):
    ..

def display(self, xpos, ypos):
    ..
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but is this a [mcve]? Can somebody copy and paste this code to see the error? Try isolating it to just a small example.

Comment: Your indentations are not right and you declare a class by using `class`. Is that your actual code? Also it will be helpful if you post the traceback of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
Class Ribbon (object): 
      def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, m, g):
      self.x=xpos
      self.y=ypos
      self.mass=m
      self.gravity=g
```

also remember that other def must be indented properly as well