# Processing.py Sketch Error: unclosed paren/quote mark

Tags: python, processing, parentheses

I fail to see where I've missed out the parentheses/quote marks in the following code, yet I get the following error:

```
processing.app.SketchException: Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?
```

Below is part of my code (for ball bouncing off wall):

```
from random import random, randint

ballList = []

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xcor = x
        self.ycor = y
        self.xvel = randint(­2, 2)           # line causing the SketchException
        self.yvel = randint(­2, 2)
        self.col = color(
            randint(0, 255),
            randint(0, 255),
            randint(0, 255))
```

I found a similar (but incomplete & yet-to-be-answered qu) here:
[Processing.py - Unknown Error on Class Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531121/processing-py-unknown-error-on-class-definition) & other forums do not address this problem clearly..

.

EDIT1: The console highlighted that the commented line above caused the error

EDIT2: I am using Processing to simulate balls bouncing off walls.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code you've shown, but neither have you shown how you know this is the offending line, nor have you shown anything to do with how Processing is actually involved in your project. It's impossible to help you with just this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good point, I have made the necessary edits now; but the problem has thankfully been solved

Answer (score 1):

Adding this response in case it helps someone else in the future. I got this error as well, found no unclosed parentheses, and tried re-writing all lines as I had copied and pasted earlier in the script. However I was still getting the same error.

Then I realized I had accidentally typed "for all" in the line that was displaying the error instead of just "for"! So I guess this error message can occur when there is another kind of syntax error in the line itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this error for almost the entire day while working on the "Python Mode". Your code looks like Py. The issue arises in the first line where you declare your first variable. It mysteriously went away when I switched to Java mode. I don't know if this helps.

P.S. Mine was a short and basic code, probably not as complex as yours is.